# jQuery performance in terms of getting attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Is there any difference in performence between these three below when it comes to getting element's attribute value?

**a) attr() function**

```
$('div').click(function() {
    var div_id = $(this).attr('id');
    // rest of the logic
});
```

**b) event object's target property**

```
$('div').click(function(e) {
    var div_id = e.target.id;
    // rest of the logic
});
```

**c) pure JS approach**

```
$('div').click(function() {
    var div_id = this.id;
    // rest of the logic
});
```

Comment: Most certainly. *Not* executing a function will always be faster than executing a function. Whether it makes any difference for the overall performance if your app/site, I doubt it. But even if there wasn't any difference, why would you ever write `$(this).attr('id')` instead of `this.id`.

Comment: Why are you asking, instead of testing with, for example, [JS Perf](http://jsperf.com)?

Comment: @Felix, my thoughts exactly. However, some people like to stick strictly to library convenctions and would go with $(this).attr('id') as a "jQuery way" of writing code.

Comment: @David, as far as it's not a sin to ask, I'm happy to do so. Plus, I get to know tools like JS Perf - thanks.

Comment: @lesssugar for performance point of view you should take a look at your selectors getting those with id is better than any other.

Comment: True. My attitude is "use the library where it makes sense".

Answer (score 0):

No doubt option c is way better as given with others :

```
$('div').click(function() {
   var div_id = this.id;
   // rest of the logic
});
```

because this is available in the browser itself and you are not using another method of any external library like the other two.

Comment: `e.target` is a standard DOM feature. Even if `e` comes from jQuery.